# Cutoff-dependent "inverse propagator" for renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, propagator

In Zee's *QFT in a Nutshell*, when introducing mass renormalization, he calculates the "inverse propagator" for a $\phi^4$ scalar field theory to order $\lambda^2$ by considering the two diagrams shown:

[image: diagrams]

and gets $k^2 - m^2 + a + b k^2 + O(k^4)$ where $a$ and $b$ are cutoff dependent. My understanding is that this comes from writing the amplitude for a single line of momentum $k$ as:
$$
\frac{1}{(k^2 - m^2)^2} (k^2 - m^2)
$$
and adding it to the amplitude for these two with external lines added:
$$
\frac{1}{(k^2 - m^2)^2} (a + bk^2)
$$

In that case wouldn't the new propagator be $\frac{1}{(k^2 - m^2)^2} (k^2 - m^2 + a + bk^2)$ instead of $\frac{1}{k^2 - m^2 + a + bk^2}$? Or am I totally thinking about it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question after thinking about it for a while: it's because the external lines themselves must follow the same summation procedure - imagine adding the same quantum fluctuations to the external lines. Thus the propagator is written as $P = P^2(1/P)$ where $1/P = A + \lambda B + \lambda^2 C + \cdots$. Clearly to zeroth order in $\lambda$ the inverse propagator is $k^2 - m^2$, and the remaining terms are just as calculated in the text.